# Windows EC2 instance inbound RDP works, but inbound HTTP does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a running Windows 2012 Server instance on EC2. I can reach it with RDP, but I cannot reach it via HTTP.

I have configured the security group to allow all inbound traffic on ports 80 and 8080. (see image). I have web servers listening on both ports. I can reach both web sites using http://localhost and http://localhost:8080 from a Web browser running on the instance.

[image: Screen shot of EC2 security group]

Why am I able to connect via RDP, but not via HTTP? I am new to the whole VPC thing. And I'm new to Windows in EC2. But I can't think of anything I missed. The routing tables look open. The elastic IP is assigned to the machine. There is a subnet attached to the VPC to give the machine its internal IP. There is an Internet Gateway attached to the VPC. The Network ACLs look wide open to me.

Comment: What about the firewall on the instance itself? Windows will automatically create a rule for RDP by default, but not for IIS.

Comment: OMG. OK, I'll try and configure the firewall.

Comment: I turned off Windows Firewall and I can reach my Web servers. Thank you. If you post an answer to the question, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Windows Firewall to make sure port 80/443 is open. Windows doesn't create rules automatically for IIS.